# Trouble loading Google sheet via API if formatted as date

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am using the Google Visualization API to read data directly from a Google Sheet url. When the entire spreadsheet id formatted at "Plain Text" works great, but if one of the columns is formatted as a "Date," the data is screwed up. Even the number of columns and rows is messed up. Any thoughts?

```
    var query=new google.visualization.Query(url);
    query.send(handleGoogleResponse);                               

function handleGoogleResponse(response) {
        var cols=data.getNumberOfColumns(); 
        var rows=data.getNumberOfRows();
        var hasLabels=data.getColumnLabel(0) ? true : false;
        ...
```

And done with formatted dates that doesn't work:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14XHFSRjFmfN6E2aGwVA9CfB-XE_zP17fwoS8RYU0SCg/edit

http://www.viseyes.org/visualeyes/?896

To see one that works replace the ?896 in the above link with ?456

Comment: Can you please add one example of a URL that has this date which is causing you problems? Or, better yet, publish and link here an example Google Sheet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I reedited the question to include a link to the doc and how I'm using it in the app.